# Replace only domain part with awk in the second column

Tags: bash, awk

when this lines are given in a file:

```
docker://docker.io/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2 docker://docker.io/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2
docker://ghcr.io/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2 docker://ghcr.io/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2
docker://ecr.aws/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2 docker://ecr.aws/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2
```

if i execute

```bash
awk -F: -v var2="example.local/" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "} {gsub(/(\/\/.*\.[a-z{2,6}]*\/)/, var2, $2)} 1'
```

results in

```
docker://docker.io/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2 docker:example.local/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2
docker://ghcr.io/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2 docker:example.local/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2
docker://ecr.aws/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2 docker:example.local/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2
```

How can i only replace the domain part in the 2nd column? In this case "docker.io|ghcr.io|ecr.aws" in a generic way.

Comment: I think when you wrote `[a-z{2,6}]` (1 character from the set of characters from a to z plus the characters `{` `2` `,` and `6`) you probably meant `[a-z]{2,6}` (2 to 6 characters from the set of characters from a-z).

Comment: `BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "}` is setting FS and OFS to their default values, overriding your preceding `-F:` statement that was very briefly changing FS to `:`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output for your posted sample input, otherwise we're just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` solution. In case `//` in output before new value is needed then change regex to `^(.*docker:\/\/)[^/]*\/(.*)` in both the solutions.

```bash
awk -v var="example.local/" '
match($0,/^(.*docker:)\/\/[^/]*\/(.*)/,arr){
  print arr[1] var arr[2]
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above `awk` code. Using GNU `awk`'s `match` function here. Where I am using regex `^(.*docker:)\/\/[^/]*\/(.*)` to do the matches. This expression is creating 2 capturing groups(1st value from starting of line to till docker:// AND 2nd after 1st occurrence of `/` which comes after docker.io|ghcr.io|ecr.aws values to till end of the line). As per GNU `awk`'s `match` function it creates an array(named arr here) which stores values of capturing groups in to it. Once `match` condition is TRUE then simply printing arr's 1st value followed by var(new value) followed by arr's 2nd value.

---

---

***Bonus solution:*** In case you are ok with `perl` one-liner solution then you may try following, using lazy matching concept in its regex to get the exact match, creating 2 capturing groups and then substituting it with only required parts only.

```bash
perl -pe 's/^(.*?\s+docker:)\/\/.*?\/(.*)$/$1\/example.local\/$2/' Input_file
```

Comment: I didn't know about the third arg of `match`; it's GNU specific but +1 nevertheless

Comment: @EdMorton, ok sir, I have seen 2nd output as as desired output by OP. if that is the output needed then script is working fine, Its 3:11 AM here so I may be wrong also but looks ok to me if the case is same which I mentioned here else I will edit code once I get up in morning, cheers.

Comment: @EdMorton, if we are talking about `//` in output I have added alternate regex for same for both solutions, I will check this post in morning sir, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it was the `//` - best I can tell that 2nd block of text the OP posted is the bad output they currently get from the script they posted.

Comment: @EdMorton, oh ok thank you sir, in 2nd samples those were not there so I didn't keep them, let's wait for OP, good night sir 

Answer (score 2):

you might try:

```bash
awk -v domain2=example.com '{sub("://[^/]*", "://" domain2, $2)} 1'
```

Answer (score 2):

For the example data, perhaps a pattern without matching `//` would be acceptable.

As you replace only 1 occurrence, you might use `sub` to match the first occurrence of the pattern.

For example

```
awk -v var2="example.local/" '{sub(/[^./]+\.[a-z]{2,6}\//, var2, $2)}1' file
```

The pattern matches:

- `[^./]+` Match 1+ chars other than `/` or `.`
- `\.[a-z]{2,6}` Match a dot and 2-6 times a char a-z
- `\/` Match `/`

Output

```
docker://docker.io/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2 docker://example.local/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2
docker://ghcr.io/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2 docker://example.local/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2
docker://ecr.aws/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2 docker://example.local/some-repo/my-image:v1.1.2
```

Else you can match the leading `docker://` at the start of the string,  and use that in the replacement:

```
awk -v var2="example.local/" '{sub(/^docker:\/\/[^./]+\.[a-z]{2,6}\//, "docker://" var2, $2)}1' file
```